# Let $A$ be a$ m \times n$ matrix. Determine whether or no the set $W=\{y: Ay=0\}$ is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix. Determine whether or no the set $W= \{y : Ay=0\}$ is a vector space. 
This proof involves nullspace work and another way of asking it is also proving that $W$ is the nullspace of $A$.

I think you can solve this with the use of the subspace theorem being that you can just prove axioms $A1$ ($U+V =$ something in the set) and $M1$ ($kU=$ something in the set) The problem that I am having here is how to set this up so that I can prove this.

Comment: Take $x,y \in W$, $c$ a constant. To prove that $W$ is a subspace, you need to see that $(x+y) \in W$ and $cx \in W$, which means, by the definition of W, that: $A(x+y)=0$ and $A(cx)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the subspace theorem is the way to go here. You first need to show that $W$ is not the empty. This is pretty easy (the zero vector should come in handy).

Next, suppose that $x,y\in W$. This means that $Ax=0$ and $Ay=0$. Therefore, 
$$A(x+y)=Ax+Ay=0+0=0.$$
Therefore $W$ is closed with respect to addition. Now suppose $x\in W$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $Ax=0$ so that
$$A(c\cdot x)=cAx=c\cdot 0=0.$$
Therefore $W$ is closed with respect to scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to show that 
$$
W=\{\vec x\in\Bbb R^n:A\vec x=\vec 0\}
$$
is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. To do so, we use the [one-step vector subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test). To do so, let $\vec x,\vec y\in W$ and let $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. Then
$$
A(\vec x+\lambda\cdot\vec y)=A\vec x+\lambda\cdot A\vec y=\vec 0+\lambda\cdot \vec0=\vec 0
$$
so that $\vec x+\lambda\cdot\vec y\in W$. Hence $W$ is a subspace.

Of course, we could alternatively note that $W=\ker T$ where $T$ is the linear transformation $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ defined by $T(\vec x)=A\vec x$, but this probably violates the spirit of the problem.